# ListView shows no items from database

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I tried many ways but I got blank layout.I changed lots of lines but the result is always the same. Should I rewrite the code and try something different. I followed some **videos** on **youtube** but nobody has the proper solution.I don't think it is caused because array got null result. Anybody knows what might be wrong:

**AirportTransportActivity**

```
public class AirportTransportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] data = new String[0];
JSONObject jsonObject = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_airport_transport);

    //Get airport details
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String getairport = intent.getStringExtra("airport");

    final TextView textViewAirport = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvairport);
    textViewAirport.setText(getairport);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());


    //List view setup
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvairport);

    //Get airport transport
    new RetrieveTask().execute();

    //Adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String strUrl = "http://my database";
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            url = new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            iStream.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            data = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                data[i] = jsonObject.getString("airporttransportname");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could please show a sample of your JSON result you get from the server?

Comment: [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"BHX Birmingham","airport":"BHX Birmingham","2":"test","airporttransportname":"test","3":"van","cartype":"van","4":"5","maxpeople":"5","5":"Birmingham i okolice","area":"Birmingham","6":"54321","contact":"54321"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"BHX Birmingham","airport":"BHX Birmingham","2":"test2","airporttransportname":"test2","3":"sedan","cartype":"sedan","4":"4","maxpeople":"4","5":"Birmingham","area":"Birmingham","6":"12345","contact":"12345"}]

Comment: did you get your code to work yet?

Comment: No, Im confused right now, I find rewriting the code best option.

Comment: I made a few changes to your code. Give it a try. Please let me know if you have any problems with it. I am not on my developing computer right now, so I was unable to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original post you have set the adapter before you have added the data. But I also suspect that you are having issues with:
`String[] data = new String[0];`

So I changed it to 
 `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();`

I also changed your `AsyncTask` a bit. Now you can do most of your parsing in the background thread. When the `doInBackground` is successful just notify the adapter of the changes in `onPostExecute`.

You will also need to check if the `ArrayList<String>` fits to your Adapter class. If not just change it as needed.

Do this instead:

```
public class AirportTransportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = AirportTransportActivity.class.getSimpleName();

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_airport_transport);

    //Get airport details
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String getairport = intent.getStringExtra("airport");

    final TextView textViewAirport = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvairport);
    textViewAirport.setText(getairport);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());


    //List view setup
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvairport);

    //Get airport transport
    new RetrieveTask().execute();
}

private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String strUrl = "http://my database";
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            url = new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            iStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.isEmpty()) return;
        try{
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int len = jsonArray.length();
            Log.e(TAG, "Lenth of json array = " + len)

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // I add the optString variation just in case the data is corrupt
                String s = jsonObject.optString("airporttransportname", "?");
                data.add(s);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);            
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer** I did this in a text editor and wasn't able to count on "auto-correct" for some of the syntax or method names--so you will need to check it.
There are some other things I would change in your code, but I wanted to leave it as close to the original as I could.

Comment: Somebody want to add a comment on why they think this answer deserves a down vote?

Comment: The app shows error on that line JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

Comment: I used this to check if data is full and thats what I get now: if(data == null){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data is Empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Full " + data + " ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        } The resul is Data Full []

Comment: @D.B. :: That is odd that you should be getting an error at the line of code, now. It is the same code you had--I just moved it inside the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: I rewrote half of the code and now it works fine, but that listview needed tremendous amount of time.

Comment: I changed the code back around a bit. Take a look. Maybe you would prefer that solution.

Comment: I appreciate that Barns and I'll test the code in a while but my new solution allows me to manipulate the code more easily.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `data` array and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` before your async task has a chance to finish. You need to set your adapter and `notifyDataSetChanged()` from within the  `onPostExecute()` method in your async task.

Just to be clear, when you call `asyncTask.execute()`, it starts the async task and then immediately keeps executing the rest of the code. So when you set your `data` array in your list view adapter, the asyncTask hasn't even finished and your array items are still null.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change anything just add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after storing all values into your `array`

> Remove this line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`in `Oncreate` ,You
>   have to use notifyDataSetChanged() when your arraylist values is getting
>   changed.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            data = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                data[i] = jsonObject.getString("airporttransportname");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Certainly the easiest. But you might want to tell the OP that he should remove `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from his `onCreate()` method since it is an unnecessary call.

Comment: The change is applied but still not working. Its same as it was before

Comment: Now it gets from JSON 2 values. I added JSON sample under my question.

Comment: @D.B. https://jsonlint.com/    check here and tell me your  response is valid or not...otherwise post your json responce into your question